# usb-otg, mtp and adb sideload not working in TWRP

Tags: twrp, usb-on-the-go

I was using LOS17 on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (t813) but I decided to go back to LOS16. So I downloaded the ROM and gapps, put them on a pen drive, rebooted my tablet in recovery mode (running latest TWRP), wiped everything (system, cache, dalvik, internal storage), connected the pendrive through OTG cable but discovered that the ROM file was corrupt, so I downloaded it again but now my tablet is no longer recognising the OTG drive.

So I tried the adb sideload method, no luck: device is not found.
MTP is enabled but PC is not seeing the device.
At this point I'm stuck. What could I do?

I do have a TWRP backup saved just before I installed LOS16 for the first time and it contains three .img files. Can I somehow use these in Download mode?

Comment: If all USB modes don't work then there are these possibilities: 1. the USB cable is defect 2. the phone USB port is defect. A defect USB port is not uncommon as the USB plug works like a lever increasing the mechanical force on the USB port and thus on the soldering points that connect the port to the phone mainboard.

Comment: I tried a different cable, so I would exclude that. The possibility that the port is defective is still real.

Comment: TWRP adb shell work? *'adb push rom.zip /tmp'* and install from TWRP menu (or use MicroSD card)

Comment: No. adb is not recognising the device. `adb devices` - No devices found